# how many 74LS low-power Schottky inputs can an output of MC9S12DG128 drive?

Tags: low-power, schottky

I need to figure this out for a project and can't seem to find the answer. Does anyone know how I can figure this out? I think there is an equation to find this and can't seem to find the specification sheet for MC9S12DG128. What do I need to figure out about the MC9S12 to find the answer?

Answer (score 1):

The MC9S12DG128 can sink or source an absolute maximum of 25mA from any GPIO pin (as stated in the datasheet).

The 74LS00 has \$I_{IH}\$ (in the example I found) of 20µA.
It has an \$I_{IL}\$ of 0.4mA though, which is higher.

25mA / 0.4mA = 62.5.

So theoretically 62 74LS00 is the absolute maximum before you break the IO pin.

Comment: Damn combined datasheets!  Wrong table!  Gah!

Answer (score 0):

The Vol specification for the MC9S12DG128 is 0.8V for 2mA or 10mA, depending on whether the output is full drive or partial drive, but the Vil for 74LS is 800mV, so there is no noise margin at those currents.

If you assume that half the current will result in half the voltage drop, so 1mA or 5mA, then you could drive (at 0.4mA per low input) 2 inputs or 12 inputs depending on the output type, with the typical 74LS amount (400mV) of noise margin.

Reference datasheet [here](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Freescale%20Semi/MC9S12DT128B%20Guide.pdf) (PDF page 94).

The low level is limiting- high TTL (actually DTL for the 74LS) levels don't require much current and have much more margin.

[image]